# Analyzing pick, group & rank data

Tags: survey, count-data, ranking, ranks

Participants completed a survey containing a pick, group and rank question. In detail, they were provided 16 items and asked to choose the ones that are relevant to them. Afterwards, they should rank these selected relevant items, i.e., most relevant item = rank 1, second relevant item = rank 2 etc.

I am looking for the best way to analyze the data obtained (beyond mere frequency counts). I already thought of calculating the average rank score for each item (i.e., sum all rank scores and divide them by the number of item selections). However, I fear this does not take the non-selected items into account. Would coding these non-selected items with e.g. "-1" be an appropriate approach? And do I need to consider anything with a view to the fact that participants chose different amounts of items (e.g., p1 chose 5 items, p2 only 3 etc.)?

Grateful for any input and happy to provide further information if needed.

Comment: There's is no *one* or *right* way to analyze data like this. Your *pick* method was originally proposed as *pick any/N* by Wayne Desarbo, perhaps the only marketing scientist ever to sit on a Nobel Laureate nomination committee. https://directory.smeal.psu.edu/wsd6 His papers on this subject are worth a look, e.g., https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221798001507  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02616247